# JavaScript: Check for "virgin" elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible yo check if an element consists only of the tag (no attributes, no contents) in JavaScript?

Example:

```
<div></div> -> true
<div id="foo"></div> -> false
<div>bar</div> -> false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the element in a variable named `element`, you could check for the number of attributes and child nodes it has. If both of these are zero, then your condition is true.

```
element.attributes.length === 0 && element.childNodes.length === 0
```

---

This will not be true though if the element contains whitespace as a child node. For example:

```
<div>   </div>
```

If the condition needs to be true in this situation as well, then, instead of checking for child nodes, you could get the contents of the element as a string, remove all whitespaces inside, and check if the resulting length is zero:

```
element.innerHTML.replace(/\s+/, '').length === 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Just check for attributes and content, something like

```
function isVirgin(element) {
    return element.attributes.length === 0 &&  
           element.innerHTML.trim().length === 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vLaTJ/)

Answer (score 3):

Others have given the ideal technique, but if you want to find **all** elements that match such requirements you can use something like (ECMA5, i.e. not IE <= 8):

```
var virginEls = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('*:empty'), function(el) {
    return !el.attributes.length;
});
```

That first finds all 'empty' elements using the CSS pseudo selector `:empty`, then further filters the set down to just those with no attributes using `array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: +1 Very nice. Should probably mention though that `:empty` won't work in IE8 and lower.

Comment: I did mention it was ECMA5 (aka almost certainly won't work in IE < 9) but yeap, can't help to be explicit.

Comment: True. Just that it's much simpler and more common to shim `Array.prototype.filter()` than to add the missing CSS3 selectors in IE8 (and IE6/7 can't have its DOM nodes extended via `.prototype`).

Answer (score 1):

One intresting special case: what about tags that only include whitespace?
If you want to include such tags in your definition of "virgin", you should use element.children, as in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/S5PXm/):

the most important piece of code is:

```
log("has " + o.attributes.length + " attributes and " + o.children.length + " children");
```